# Defining 5x5 matrix

Tags: prolog

the problem is ; we have a function take 3 argument,
like; func ( [[0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]], (1, 1), X ) the first one is nested list, which is 
show 5x5 matrix and 1s means it is full, 0 means empty and,
the second parameter (1,1) our starting point 1st row 1st column,
the 3rd parameter X is ;  variable that we will unify with 
the points that are accessible from the starting point which is (1,1)
so if asked;

```
?- func ( [ [0,0,0,1] [0,0,1,0] [0,0,1,1] [0,0,1,0] ], (1,1), X).
X = (1, 1);

X = (1, 2);

X = (1, 3);

X = (2, 2);

X = (3, 2);

X = (4, 1);

X = (4, 2);

false.
```

when we start from (1,1) we can move up, down, left and right; 
since no left and up movement while on (1,1) look right if empty, write it, look down empty write down, go the (1,2) again, move right or left or up or down, and so on.

here the reason why we didn't write the outputs, (2,4) (4,4)
if for example point (2,3) is full and (2,4) is empty 
we look that can we go point (2,4) one by one, I mean, 
if left , up and down of them is full, we can't go point (2,4) using this point, since they are full.

Comment: Could you name your question more appropriately

Comment: ok, we have nested list [[0,0][0,1]] and a starting poin (a,b) and X
which we will show our epmty points.
so x will be (1,1)(1,2)(2,1) since nested list is 2x2 matrix and 
1 means point(1,2) full and other points are 0 means empty and they are wanted.
here is open, I think

Answer (score 10):

My solution: get the textbook, sit at the computer, and figure it out for yourself! Simply labelling something as homework doesn't excuse not doing it yourself.

Comment: @fortran, I also took the liberty of looking at some of your answers to other questions ..nice responses! (just in case you're wondering why your reputation got a spike up today)

Answer (score 0):

lastly I done it, here is the code;

```
%returns the nth element from the list
nth([F|_],1,F).
nth([_|R],N,M) :- N > 1, N1 is N-1, nth(R,N1,M).

%returns true if cell is empty: gets the cell value at (StartRow,StartColumn) and returns whether the value is 0
isempty(Maze,StartRow,StartColumn) :- nth(Maze,StartRow,Line),nth(Line,StartColumn,Y), Y == 0.

%returns the head of the list
head([Elem|_],Elem).

%find accessible returns empty list if not in maze size (1 to N for row and column)
findaccessible(Maze, (StartRow,StartColumn), [], _) :- head(Maze,L),length(L,N), (StartColumn > N ; StartRow > N ; StartColumn < 1 ; StartRow < 1).

%find all empty cells and retain them in X. L retains the current found cells in order to avoid returning to visited positions.
findaccessible(Maze, (StartRow,StartColumn), X, L) :- 
  %if cell is empty, retain position and add it to the list
  isempty(Maze,StartRow,StartColumn) -> (union(L,[(StartRow,StartColumn)],L1),X1 = [(StartRow,StartColumn)], 

  %check right column and if element not visited, find all accessible cells from that point and unify the lists
  SR is StartRow, SC is StartColumn+1,(member((SR,SC),L) -> union(X1,[],X2) ; (findaccessible(Maze, (SR,SC), Tmp1, L1), union(X1,Tmp1,X2))),
  %check down row and if element not visited, find all accessible cells from that point and unify the lists
  SR2 is StartRow+1,SC2 is StartColumn, (member((SR2,SC2),L) -> union(X2,[],X3) ; (findaccessible(Maze, (SR2,SC2), Tmp2, L1), union(X2,Tmp2,X3))),
  %check left column and if element not visited, find all accessible cells from that point and unify the lists

  SR3 is StartRow, SC3 is StartColumn-1, (member((SR3,SC3),L) -> union(X3,[],X4) ; (findaccessible(Maze, (SR3,SC3), Tmp3, L1), union(X3,Tmp3,X4))),
  %check up row and if element not visited, find all accessible cells from that point and unify the lists
  SR4 is StartRow-1, SC4 is StartColumn, (member((SR4,SC4),L) -> union(X4,[],X) ; (findaccessible(Maze, (SR4,SC4), Tmp4, L1), union(X4,Tmp4,X)))) ; X = [].

%lists each result
%if no more results return false
results(_,[]) :- fail.
%return the result or return the rest of the results
results(X,[Head|Rest]) :- X = Head ; results(X,Rest).

%accessible predicate that finds all empty accessible cells and then list each of them
accessible(Maze, (StartRow,StartColumn), X) :- findaccessible(Maze, (StartRow,StartColumn), Lst, []), !, results(X,Lst).

%sample test run
%accessible([[0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]], (1, 1), X).
```

Comment: I improved the formatting.  Either indent each line four spaces yourself, or use the little button with the 1s and 0s to designate something as code.